# Java Socket read and write unexpected behavior

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I faced an issue while transferring file from client to server. So I did a simple client and server code in java using sockets. I found some unexpected behavior. I can't find why it happens so. Following is the code

Server side code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class Server
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    ServerSocket ser;
    try {
        ser=new ServerSocket(9000);
        Socket cnfcon=ser.accept();
        OutputStream outstr=cnfcon.getOutputStream();
        InputStream inpstr=cnfcon.getInputStream();
        PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(outstr,true);
        BufferedReader inp=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inpstr));
        File f=new File("test.txt");
        InputStream fis= new FileInputStream(f);
        long size=f.length();
        System.out.println("Start Server");
        out.println(f.getName());
        out.println(size);
        byte[] buff1=new byte[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        byte[] buff2=new byte[]{7,1,2,3,8,5,6,7,8,9};

        outstr.write(buff1);
        //inpstr.read(); -- tried including this and removing this
        outstr.write(buff2);
        //inpstr.read();


        fis.close();
        inp.close();
        ser.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
 };
```

client side code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class test
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {
    Socket cnfcon=new Socket("127.0.0.1",9000);
    OutputStream outstr=cnfcon.getOutputStream();
    InputStream inpstr=cnfcon.getInputStream();
    PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(outstr,true);
    BufferedReader inp=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inpstr));

    File f=new File(inp.readLine()+"t"); //"t" - dummy
    f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(f);

    int size=Integer.parseInt(inp.readLine());
    byte buff[]=new byte[1024];


    System.out.println("Start Client");

    inpstr.read(buff, 0, 10);
    disp(buff);
    //outstr.write(1); -- tried including this and removing this
    inpstr.read(buff, 0, 10);
    disp(buff);
    //outstr.write(1); 1 - dummy value


    fos.close();
    out.close();
    cnfcon.close();

}
public static void disp(byte buff[])
{
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        System.out.print(buff[i]);
    System.out.println();
}
};
```

I am sending two buffers from server to client.

Here I expect first buffer should come first and next for next time.
But its unpredictable.

Some times it works as expected. Some times it gets the 2nd buff for both time. Some times all bytes in the buffer are zero.

I tried adding outstr.flush() before the message passing.

Is there any other way to implement this?

To be more clear, it seems client is not waiting for server to send or vice versa.

The output is different every time.

Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: FYI, I am using jdk8

Comment: I strongly suspect this has to do with the fact that read() does _not_ necessarily read all that you tell it to.  You need a loop to continue until all of the data has definitely been read.

Comment: That, and failure to appreciate that TCP is an octet/byte streaming service.  It cannot transfer 'messages' any longer than one byte.  Send 20 bytes in two 10-byte send calls, and you may receive all 20 bytes in one read, or one byte in 20 reads, or anything in between.

Answer (score 3):

The problems are at least two:

1. You're ignoring the count returned by `read()`, and assuming it filled the buffer. It isn't obliged to do that. It isn't contracted to transfer more than one byte. You have to loop:

   ```
   while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
   {
       out.write(buffer, 0, count);
   }
   ```
2. Data is disappearing into the buffered readers/writers/streams, and it is caused by using too many parts of the I/O stack. Don't use multiple readers, writers, and streams, on the same socket. Use a single output stream or writer and a single input stream or reader for the life of the socket. As you are writing binary data you shouldn't be using readers or writers at all.

Contrary to other answers here, it isn't necessary to add flushes or sleeps in this code, as long as you close everything correctly, or to fiddle around with `available()` results either.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a `Thread.sleep()` in the client when it receives the buffers? Not sure if it will work.

Comment: Well, it will sleep, but it's just literally a waste of time.

Answer (score -2):

Let me guess , you are on Microsoft windows ?

First chunk your data into small chunks ( let's say 1kb ), but you are already doing that  and then sleep a little bit in both your read and write loops. Call flush when possible after writes, and Be sure to make sure you don't read more than input stream.availible()

Your code should work on every other os without issue , without modification.

Comment: Why? Why use small chunks? What are the sleeps intended to accomplish? Why flush after write when close flushes everything? Why fiddle around with `available()` instead of blocking? What specific problem with the OP's code will any of these measures address?

Comment: because windows sockets in java behave in mysterious ways, especially when dealing with localhost.We had a bug here which was effectively data truncation at random places during transfer from one process to another, with fixed sized but larger packets (about 15kb), it appeared that when there was other network activity on the given machine it would hang.  available would return a certain number, we would be good to read that number of bytes. and then if 'looped on quickly' it would return '0' given a sleep it would return allow it to return some more data (Code : http://pastebin.com/GADwPQ5D)

Comment: Your code isn't valid because of (1) above. That's why you've had to add all the flying buttresses. The only way `InputStream.read(byte[] buffer)` can return zero is if a zero-length buffer is supplied. I've been using the loop above on all platforms since 1997 and never a problem. You don't seem to have heard of `Socket.setSoTimeout` either.

Comment: I have been using something similar for a similar amount of time, the method that was posted but we had a IPC feature originally inserting into a normal array of bytes, but we were finding that it would start to leave the array half empty out early when running unit tests on a windows jenkins slave (which happened to double as a co-workers workstation) it only appeared a day before release so myself and 2 co-workers (between the 3 of us we have over 72 years of development experience.) and this was the only solution which consistently worked. its hacky and time based and we hated it worked.

Comment: It's allowed to do that. It isn't obliged to fill the buffer. See the Javadoc. It's only obliged to transfer at least one byte, or return EOS, or throw an exception. It isn't necessary to use small chunks or add sleeps or call `available()` or keep asking the time to solve that. Just loop until you get everything you're expecting. If everybody had to write code like yours, everybody would, and e.g. the JDK would be full of it too. It isn't. Have a look at the source for `DataInputStream.readFully()` for example.

Comment: give me a minute I will find the code which originally was failing tests in our svn, it will make you litrally poop yourself.

Comment: I rather doubt it. Tomcat doesn't have code like this. The JDK doesn't have code like this. If this was a real problem everybody would be doing it, and they aren't. If you have a question about why your code didn't work I suggest you ask it here as a question.

Comment: Don't really have a question as I have not came across a similar issue since (and I honestly dont do jvm to jvm IPC with raw sockets on the same machine very often, pretty sure the JDK and tomcat dont either. ) 

But I digress, this is the code that completely exploded, 
http://pastebin.com/fR1CWnH3 , reading from other inputstreams (file, gz, byte arrays, remote sockets.,)worked fine, but reading from a socket generated by a call to serversocket.accept() when the serversocket was listening to all interfaces on the machine and the client socket was created in another jvm caused an explosion

Comment: I should also point out that this code _DID_  pass last april, when written and started to fail in august, continued to pass unit tests from our CI system on 3 other test boxes (OSX, and 2x linux.)  just windows 7 all of a sudden started to crap itself, and then it became fairly consistent, in doing so (albiet at random positions. )

Comment: You could, and should, replace the entire method that 'exploded' with `DataInputStream.readFully()`. It was poor qualty code in the first place, and what you replaced it with was no improvement. For example it allows data overruns and then just throws an exception if they happen, instead of preventing them in the first place, which is easy enough. `readFully()` manages it OK.

Comment: ^^ What @EJP says.  Timer/Sleep-based 'protocols' do not work reliably on a byte streaming service.  All such approaches are borken by design.

Comment: @ejp we actually required that exception since the protocol that we were supporting has fixed size messages and the third party hardware implementation that we are emulating in could send a 'longer' packet in the event of  a error, and desired behavior would be to close the socket (since it is a single message per socket anyway) and notify the user because it would be oversampled data.. Atleast with using timing we could check the length of the payload after the fact.

Comment: @ejp I just checked the code that you called poor quality and it appears that our initial implementation is pretty much identical to DataInputStream.readFully() except for the fact that we throw a exception when we know there is a issue.  (if the data was too long then the whole sample would be garbage anyway. )

Comment: @DamianNikodem Rubbish. `DataInputStream.readFully()` does not rely on sleeps or timeouts.