# Read on SocketChannel reaches end-of-stream after ServerSocketChannel performs accept

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, channel, socketchannel

I've pasted a server side code snippet below. This server code works under normal circumstances, however, the following scenario manages to break the code.
Server and client are on the same machine. I used the loopback address, and the actual IP address, it makes no difference.

**Scenario**

1. Server is online, Client makes request (`WritableByteChannel.write(ByteBuffer src)` returns 12 byte, which is the correct size, but as research revealed that only means the 12 bytes are written to the TCP buffer).
2. Server program is turned off. Client notices that the channel is closed on the remote side and closes it on its own side, it doesn't make any requests.
3. Server is online again.
4. Client tries to make a request, but fails, because the channel is closed/invalid and can't be reused (even though server is online again).
5. Client **checks server's online status**, gets positive result, connects again and immediately makes another request.
6. Server accepts client (code below), after that processes the if clause with the `key.isReadable()` condition, **but** then fails on the read, which indicates end-of-stream.

It would be too complex to create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), please comment if important information is missing or this is too abstract and I'll provide further information.

**Question**

How can a freshly created/accepted channel fail on the read operation?
What am I missing? What steps can I undertake to prevent this?

I already tried wireshark, but I can't capture any packets on the designated TCP port, even if the communication is acutally working.

---

**Problem/Additional Info**

- It's possible to capture packets into .pcap file with [RawCap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap)
- The problem was the way the client checked the server status. I've added the method below.

---

**Code snippets**

Snippet 1

```
    while (online)
    {
      if (selector.select(5000) == 0)
        continue;

      Iterator<SelectionKey> it = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
      while (it.hasNext())
      {
        SelectionKey key = it.next();
        it.remove();

        if (key.isAcceptable())
        {
          log.log(Level.INFO, "Starting ACCEPT!");
          ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
          SocketChannel channel = serverSocketChannel.accept();

          channel.configureBlocking(false);
          channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);

          log.log(Level.INFO, "{0} connected to port {1}!",
              new Object[] {channel.socket().getInetAddress().getHostAddress(), isa.getPort()});
        }

        boolean accepted = false;
        if (key.isReadable())
        {
          log.log(Level.INFO, "Starting READ!");
          SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

          bb.clear();
          bb.limit(Header.LENGTH);
          try
          {
            NioUtil.read(channel, bb); // server fails here!
          }
          catch (IOException e)
          {
            channel.close();
            throw e;
          }
          bb.flip();
```

Snippet 2

```
  public static ByteBuffer read(ReadableByteChannel channel, ByteBuffer bb) throws IOException
  {
    while (bb.remaining() > 0)
    {
      int read = 0;
      try
      {
        read = channel.read(bb);
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
        log.log(Level.WARNING, "Error during blocking read!", e);
        throw e;
      }

      // this causes the problem... or indicates it
      if (read == -1)
      {
        log.log(Level.WARNING, "Error during blocking read! Reached end of stream!");
        throw new ClosedChannelException();
      }
    }

    return bb;
  }
```

Snippet 3

```
  @Override
  public boolean isServerOnline()
  {
    String host = address.getProperty(PropertyKeys.SOCKET_SERVER_HOST);
    int port = Integer.parseInt(address.getProperty(PropertyKeys.SOCKET_SERVER_PORT));

    boolean _online = true;
    try
    {
      InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(host), port);
      SocketChannel _channel = SocketChannel.open();
      _channel.connect(addr);
      _channel.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      _online = false;
    }
    return _online;
  }
```

**Solution**

The problem was not the method that checked, if the service is available/the server is online. The problem was the second point EJP mentioned.

Specific input was expected from the server and it was left in an inconsistent state if that conditions were not met.
I've added some fallback measures, now the the reconnect process - including the check method - is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly the client must have closed the connection. That's the only way `read()` returns -1.

Notes:

1. You're throwing the inappropriate `ClosedChannelException` when `read()` returns -1. That exception is thrown by NIO when *you've* already closed the *channel* and continue to use it. It has nothing to do with end of stream, and shouldn't be used for that. If you must throw something, throw `EOFException`.
2. You also shouldn't loop the way you are. You should only loop while `read()` is returning a positive number. At present you are starving the select loop while trying to read data that may never arrive.

Comment: So that means I should thouroghly revise the reconnect process. The next time I'm at work, I'll check for some hidden `close()`s (...will be next week, since I'm a student) and accept your answer.

Comment: Thx also for your second point. I know what you mean, but this is only part of a little handshake (with 2 small protocl units, which are sent in one piece), the main communication however uses non-blocking read

Comment: @mike Doesn't matter. It's wrong and needs fixing. Otherwise when it does break someone else may make it even worse. Case in point [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28421784/207421).

Comment: I've added more information to the question. The problem was the way I implemented the method that checks whether the server is online (it attempts to create a connection and closes it. If no exception is thrown. the server's service is available). After I removed it, the reconnect process works, but I don't understand why. I managed to get wireshark running, but even that did not add any insight. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I think the problem is related to your second point! The server is left in an inconsistent state. I'll accept your answer! Thank you!

Comment: You write 'Clearly the client must have closed the connection. That's the only way read() returns -1.' that is incorrect. On android the rad might return -1 if there simply is no data, yet the connection is still open.

Comment: @user458577 It is you who is incorrect. If there is no data in non-blocking mode, `read()` will return *zero.* Not -1. -1 has exactly one meaning: end of stream: the peer closed the connection.